# Hide NSWindow titlebar background like Messages.app

Tags: macos, cocoa, nswindow, osx-yosemite

I'm relative new to OS X development (coming from iOS).

How can I archive a similar window like in the messages app for OS X?

I think I must create a NSWindow subclass and override something? Any idea what?

[image: Messages.app]

OS X Yosemite is the deployment target. No need to support older OS.

Comment: Hi Did you find the answer? If you found the answer please post the solution.

Comment: I've found the solution, but I'm on holiday right now and can't post the details. I just remember that NSWindow has a property to remove the title bar background.

Comment: I believe that you can enable the full-size content view to do something like this...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution.
You have to create a subclass of `NSWindowController` and in the `windowDidLoad` method, you have to put this code:

```
self.window!.titlebarAppearsTransparent = true
```

to make the whole thing work, you have to activate "Full Size Content View" in Interface Builder.

Answer (score 3):

`titlebarAppearsTransparent` is available in OS X 10.10.

For OS X 10.9 and under,

set `window.backgroundColor` and add `NSTexturedBackgroundWindowMask` to style mask.